# Extended Stats elasticsearch Standard Deviation population or sample?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, statistics

Is the elasticsearch extended stats standard deviation calculated as the sample standard deviation or the population standard deviation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [InternalExtendedStats.java](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/1047e8bce586eff75f3fa89a76310c13bf170ded/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/search/aggregations/metrics/stats/extended/InternalExtendedStats.java) source code, variance and standard deviation appear to be the population values:

```
@Override
public double getVariance() {
    return (sumOfSqrs - ((sum * sum) / count)) / count;
}

@Override
public double getStdDeviation() {
    return Math.sqrt(getVariance());
}
```